# Glassfish v2.1.1 and java-web-start 

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I've started a job that uses Glassfish 2.1.1 app server and noticed there's a java-web-start directory under the domain1 folder. In That folder there are empty directories which correspond 1:1 with ear (and other files) files deployed under ....\domain1\applications\j2ee-apps.

What is the purpose of the java-web-start folder and why does it have those empty directories in it?

New to Glassfish.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish allows the user to launch a local client which can access the application inside Glassfish directly.  The launching happens with Java WebStart.

See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/jws-glassfish/ for an introduction.